# Transmit variables between ionic 4 components in the differents moduls

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-components

configuration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QycZ.png)

**Desired operation:**
On the home page I display a list of candidates, click on a candidate, I display its details on the profile page.

I wish to transmit the candidate table, candidates: Candidate [] who is booting into home.ts to my profile.ts file

The HomePage component and ProfilPage are completely different and with different modules.

The parent relationship => child does not work, the opposite also.

And I do not see how to use a service, because the data is declare in a candidate.ts which is a class.

I put in screen the code relating to the two files
Thanks you so match for your help

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Candidat } from '../models/candidat';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  candidats: Candidat[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.candidats = [
      new Candidat(
        '/assets/candidats/ghani-mahdi.jpg',
        'toto',
        'titi',
        57,
        'A',
        'organization',
        'tag',
        'biography',
        'electoralProgram',
        12,
        -6
      ),
      new Candidat(
        '/assets/candidats/nekkaz.jpg',
        'yoyo',
        'yiyi',
        30,
        'B',
        'organization',
        'tag',
        'biography',
        'electoralProgram',
        12,
        -6),
      new Candidat(
        '/assets/candidats/tahar-missoum.jpeg',
        'lolo',
        'lili',
        38,
        'C',
        'organization',
        'tag',
        'biography',
        'electoralProgram',
        12,
        -6
      )];
    console.log(this.candidats);
  }
  select() {
    console.log("c'est moi");
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('profil');
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      A la une ...
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54959666/edit#
<ion-content>

  <ion-card class="welcome-card" *ngFor='let candidat of candidats, let i=index' (click)='select()' >
    <ion-img src={{candidat.picture}}></ion-img>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{candidat.lastName}} {{candidat.firstName}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{candidat.old}} ans - {{candidat.nationality}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <div>
        <p>{{candidat.organization}}</p>
        <p>{{candidat.tag}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" color="danger"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="danger">{{candidat.negativeVote}}</ion-badge>

      <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="secondary">{{candidat.positiveVote}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-card-content>

  </ion-card>
 
</ion-content>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page';
import { Candidat } from '../models/candidat';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profil',
  templateUrl: './profil.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profil.page.scss'],
})
export class ProfilPage implements OnInit {

  @Input() candidats: Candidat[];


  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.candidats);
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Candidat
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding >
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">

    <ion-img src="/assets/candidats/anonyme-user.jpg"></ion-img>

    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Biographie: </ion-card-title>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <ion-card-title>Programme éléctorale:</ion-card-title>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" color="danger"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="danger">negativeVote</ion-badge>

      <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="secondary">positiveVote</ion-badge>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

```js
export class Candidat {
    constructor(
        public picture: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public firstName: string,
        public old: number,
        public nationality: string,
        public organization: string,
        public tag: string,
        public biography: string,
        public electoralProgram: string,
        public positiveVote: number,
        public negativeVote: number) {
    }
}
```

[Files tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu3WW.png)

[home/home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyagr.png)

[home/home.ts (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1rbC.png)

[home/home.ts (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNVvF.png)

[profil/profil.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37TMe.png)

[profil/profil.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9MIC.png)

Comment: I think you could use a service very easily, just declare a variable to that service named "currentCandidate" and make getter and setter methods in that service for it, set the candidate prior to navigating and then get it when entering the new details page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you tell me how to do ?? I do not see the logic